# How can I get all data from a model, except one?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to retrieve all users' data, except one. For that, I used the following query:

```
$users=User::whereNotIn('name',['admin'])->pluck('id','name');
```

When I dd() the output, I see all the users' data, except the one. But when I send the query results in the `foreach()` loop on the view page, I see

> `Trying to get property of non-object`

Error in view page. What's the error here?

Here is the *foreach* loop I used on the view page:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
          <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What is the property causing the error? `id` ? `name` ? or you trying to get something else.

Comment: The Error Like `Trying to get property of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\auth\app\Modules\Permission\Views\assign_role.blade.php)` not any specific one

Comment: @Hola please show this view.

Comment: in your foreach  loop you are doing something that causes the error obviously. anything you are using in the view, add it to `pluck()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pluck()` creates an array with `[id => name]` structure, so change the code in `assign_rol‌​e.blade.php` to:

```
@foreach ($users as $id => $name)
    <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $name }}</option>                        
@endforeach
```

And `pluck()` parameters to:

```
->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Answer (score 15):

Use

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();
```

This one, except the currently logged in user. You can set an admin id in such a field.

Ir you can use this also:

```
$users = User::all()->except(Auth::id());
```

Both work!

Comment: this also works: `$users = User::all()->except(1);` and `$users = User::all()->except($user->id());`

Answer (score 0):

Using the exception everywhere in your application will lead to a big mess in your code, so whenever you want to dig into your users, you'll need to except yourself... Imagine you wanted to except the user X or Y too later?
It's kind of an unnecessary repetition.

```php
User::all()->except(Auth::id())
```

Instead, you can just override the `all` method and set a global exception.
Add the following to your User Model:

```php
 /**
    * get all users except specified ones
    *
    * @param  array|mixed  $keys
    * @return array
    */
    public static function all($keys = null)
    {
        $data = parent::all(); # grep data from parent

        return $data->except(auth()->id); # except whoever you wanted
    }
```

And you can use your `all` as you used to do wherever you wanted!

```php
User::all(); // This will exclude you
```